# Testing BatchApexErrorEvent trigger

Tags: apex, batch, platform-event

I have a batch class which implements the *Database.RaisesPlatformEvents* interface. This interface has recently been introduced and helps log unexpected exceptions: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_batchapexerrorevent.htm

It works well and I have implemented a trigger which calls a handler class to log the error permanently in a separate object:

```
trigger LogBatchApexErrorEvent on BatchApexErrorEvent (after insert){
    if(Trigger.IsInsert && Trigger.IsAfter){
        LogBatchApexErrorEvent_Handler.persistLog(Trigger.New);
    }
}
```

My test batch class looks somewhat like this:

```
public with sharing class TestBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.RaisesPlatformEvents {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        String query = 'SELECT Id FROM Account';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<SObject> scope){
        Integer i = 1 / 0;
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){ }
}
```

The problem is, it seems impossible to write a test class for this. I currently have this test method:

```
static testMethod void testBatchApexErrorEvent() {
    insert new Account(Name = 'Test Account');

    try {
        Test.startTest();
            TestBatch tb = new TestBatch();
            Database.executeBatch(tb); 
        Test.stopTest();
    } catch(System.MathException e){}

    System.assertEquals(1, [SELECT Id FROM Log__c].size());
}
```

However, the BatchApexErrorEvent is a Platform Event so is asynchronous - which means that at the time my `System.assertEquals` line runs it hasn't actually fired yet.

I also tried throwing a BatchApexErrorEvent manually, but I get the following error: *DML operation Insert not allowed on BatchApexErrorEvent*. This is my attempt:

```
BatchApexErrorEvent event = new BatchApexErrorEvent();
EventBus.publish(event);
```

Despite this being the way BatchApexErrorEvents are tested in this blogpost on the topic, it doesn't seem possible anymore: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/01/building-a-batch-retry-framework-with-batchapexerrorevent.html

Considering there is no way to either a) test two asynchronous processes in one test method or b) manually throw a BatchApexErrorEvent, is there currently any way for me to test this? :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So as I can see from your code Divide by zero will throw an exception. Which inturn will fire `BatchApexErrorEvent` . The thing we need to look for is this is the test context. The events will not deliver unless you force it to deliver.

Thus you have to call `Test.getEventBus().deliver();`, this will ensure your triggers on platform events are fired and you can do successful assert.

```
static testMethod void testBatchApexErrorEvent() {
   insert new Account(Name = 'Test Account');

   try{
        Test.startTest();
        TestBatch tb = new TestBatch();
        Database.executeBatch(tb); 
        Test.getEventBus().deliver();
        Test.stopTest();
    } catch(System.MathException e){}
    Test.getEventBus().deliver(); 

    System.assertEquals(1, [SELECT Id FROM Log__c].size());
}
```

Source: [Deliver Test Event Messages on Demand with Test.getEventBus().deliver()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_test_deliver.htm)

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work, if I remove the try-catch block the test fails with: 'System.MathException: Divide by 0'. If I reintroduce the try-catch block, however, my trigger doesn't seem to be firing - regardless of whether I put the 'Test.getEventBus().deliver();' before or after 'Test.stopTest();'.

Comment: Ah, got it - I moved the 'Test.getEventBus().deliver();' after the try-catch block and that did it. I'll edit your answer and mark it as correct - the key was that method!