# Not able to execute BatchApexErrorEvent trigger from Batch

Tags: apex, batchapexerrorevent

I am trying the BatchApexErrorEvent to handle the Batch Exception but the BatchApexErrorEvent trigger is not firing when there is an exception being thrown from a Batch class.

> TestBatch.cls

```
public with sharing class TestBatch implements 
    //Implementing the necessory Intefaces
    Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.RaisesPlatformEvents {

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        String query = 'SELECT Id FROM Account';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<SObject> scope){
        //Throwing a custom exception
        throw new myException('throwing this Exception');
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){ }

    //Custom exception
    public class myException extends Exception {}
}
```

> BatchErrorsTrigger.trigger

```
trigger BatchErrorsTrigger on BatchApexErrorEvent (after insert) {

    System.debug('Trigger Executed');
}
```

I am not able to figure out the issue here.
(**I am using a scratch Org**).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing BatchApexErrorEvent trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/263419/testing-batchapexerrorevent-trigger)

Comment: @PranayJaiswal this is not the duplicate, I am not able to execute the trigger after throwing the exception from Batch class. The question you have mentioned is related issue with writing a test class for BatchApexErrorEvent trigger.

Comment: Have you enabled debug log for Automated process? to see debug log? Retracted Close vote. +1

Comment: @PranayJaiswal thanks a ton, you saved my day. I was looking for the logs in debug log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Platform Event trigger runs in the context of an Automated Process.

You have to set the new Trace Flag to Entity Type "Automated Process"

src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe_debug.htm